# arkit showPhysicsShapes larger than node

Tags: swift, arkit, scnnode, scnscene

I am using arkit and trying to have two node collide but the collisions appears to happen too early. When I do

`ballsSceneView.debugOptions = .showPhysicsShapes`

I see that the physic shape is larger than the actual node. Attached a photo

[image]

How can I change the physical shape in order to be the same size of the node?